# Installing pytesser

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr, tesseract

I'm new to python and would like to install and use the pytesser OCR library. All of the other modules that I've installed, I've used easy_install, which has worked fine. But pytesser is the first that I've had to install by hand using Google Code's .zip file.

Per the instructions in the readme (https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/wiki/README) I extracted the contexts to my C:\Python27\Scripts file. However when I try:

```
from pytesser import *
```

within the Python Shell, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from pytesser import *
ImportError: No module named pytesser
```

Any ideas? Windows 7. Python 2.7. My other scripts using modules such as PIL, Scrapy, Numpy have been working fine.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Are your pytesser files in the same directory as the file the import statement is in (the one you're writing)?

Comment: How know where the python shell CLI runs its code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `C:\Python27\Scripts` for 3rd party modules, you should use `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` instead.

Comment: @Sekai I'd use `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (PEP-370)

Comment: Any help here please? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604862/no-module-name-pil-and-no-module-name-pytesser-visual-studio

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution, but this works for me. Please do correct me if this is incorrect in any way.

1. Unzip the folder & paste it in your Python2x\Lib folder
2. Rename it to pytesser (I'm not too sure if this is a necessary step)
3. Duplicate the tesseract.py file and rename it as **__init__.py**
4. Open **__init__.py**
5. Change the line tesseract_exe_name = "tesseract" to 
   tesseract_exe_name = 'C:\Python27\Lib\pytesser\tesseract'

Done.

Comment: I've downloaded pytesser from google code, but there is no `tesseract.py`. I found it is actually `python-tesseract` (https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/). Is it the library you've also installed?

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly for me too except that I had to name the init file \_\_init\_\_.py

Comment: Additionally i had to change the line import Image to from PIL import Image

Comment: I had to change the import for `Image` to `from PIL import Image`

Comment: For me, the last step is 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pytesser/tesseract'

Answer (score 2):

So I'm using w10 64 bits.
And it took me some time to understand how you have to install it to be able to use it.

How to :

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytesser/downloads

download pytesser_v0.0.1.zip

unzip

move files in the project

rename import Image to "from PIL import Image" in the pytesser.py

=== Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Yaitzme answer - another fix you may need (I'm using Python Tools for Visual Studio on Windows 7 64-bit)...

Once I renamed the pytesser.py file to __init__ I had to put a double backslash in the line e.g.

tesseract_exe_name = ‘C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pytesser\\tesseract’

as the single backslash '\tesseract' was interpreting the '\t' as a new tab symbol and breaking the path! Put my install instructions [here](https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2016/01/01/ocr-using-augmented-reality/)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with Python not being able to find your C:\Python27\Scripts directory because it's not in your PYTHONPATH.

Python looks in certain directories for files when you run an `import` command, they're described here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Your main options are:

1) Tell Python to look in your Scripts folder. This involves adding the folder to your Python path, see here [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

2) Put your script in a folder which is already searched by Python. This is wRAR's answer, to use the standard Python 3rd-party modules directory, see here http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#how-installation-works

3) Have the pytesser file in Python's current directory. `import os` followed by `os.getcwd()` will show you python's current directory, where the code is running (in a sense). `os.chdir("my/other/dir")` changes the current directory. See [How to know/change current directory in Python shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248397/how-to-know-change-current-directory-in-python-shell) for more detail.

Comment: The OP tried to install the module into the system, not to import it from the local directory.

Comment: According to https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/wiki/README "PyTesser has no installation functionality in this release." Therefore he needs to have the .py file in his Python path. I address this at the end of my answer. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, he needs to have the .py file in his Python path and that has nothing to do with the working directory. The last part of your answer assumes you can import modules from PYTHONPATH only after you change working directory which is wrong.

Comment: I was checking that the problem was indeed PYTHONPATH, being in the same directory works around this problem http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Yes, now the last part is less wrong, though it is still not necessary for the original question as we know what the OP has done wrong.

Comment: How is it at all wrong? I agree the conventional place to put 3rd party libraries is Lib\site-packages, but any module in a directory in the Python path is found.

Answer (score -3):

You may got sth wrong. 
I try pytesser yesterday, maybe you should not put the pytesser file into the script folder. try the working dir, alongside with your code.

```
>>> import pytesser
>>> print pytesser
<module 'pytesser' from 'E:\Desktop\jiaoben\OCR\pytesser.pyc'
```