# Installing pytesser on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, pytesser

I want to use pytesser OCR and I would like to make same changes in the system so that I can import it as a module from anywhere in the system.
I tried using advice given on ([Installing pytesser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567141/installing-pytesser)) but It's not working for me.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pytesser/ Read this. I think `pytesser` for windows only. For ubuntu you have to install `pytesseract`. It can be done like this  'pip install pytesseract`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
pip install pytesseract
```

You should use PIL to open an image and feed pytesseract.
PIL, is short for Python Image Library. Just a image library.

pytesseract is a wrapper of tesseract.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract 
im = Image.open('/home/xxxxxxx/Downloads/img.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print (text)
```