# _socket module import error on fresh python 3.3.5 install

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I installed python 3.35 and I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Augusto/PycharmProjects/Plot/Database.py", line 48, in <module>
import socket
File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

I'm running it on Windows 7  64 bits. I tried both Python installations (Windows x86-64 MSI installer and Windows x86 MSI installer) but both present the same error. I removed the python 2.7 installation from the path in the chance it was causing the error, but no luck.

EDIT: `os.system('listdlls %d' % os.getpid())`

```
Base               Size         Path    
0x000000001d000000 0xa000 C:\Python33\python.exe    
0x0000000077b40000 0x1a9000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll    
0x00000000756f0000 0x3f000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll    
0x0000000075690000 0x5c000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll    
0x0000000075680000 0x8000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll    
0x000000001d000000 0xa000 C:\Python33\python.exe    
0x0000000077d20000 0x180000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll    
0x0000000076b80000 0x110000 C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll    
0x0000000076a20000 0x47000 C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll    
0x000000001e000000 0x294000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python33.dll    
0x0000000075880000 0x100000 C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll    
0x0000000076500000 0x90000 C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll    
0x0000000076b00000 0xa000 C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll    
0x0000000076760000 0x9d000 C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll    
0x0000000076800000 0xac000 C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll    
0x00000000768b0000 0xa0000 C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll    
0x0000000076590000 0x19000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll    
0x0000000076400000 0xf0000 C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll    
0x0000000075750000 0x60000 C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll    
0x0000000075740000 0xc000 C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll    
0x0000000076cd0000 0xc4a000 C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll    
0x0000000076700000 0x57000 C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll    
0x0000000062ba0000 0xbf000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR100.dll    
0x0000000076050000 0x60000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL    
0x00000000757b0000 0xcc000 C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll    
0x00000000755d0000 0x35000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll    
0x000000000f000000 0x6000 C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\detoured.dll    
0x00000000739f0000 0x4c000 C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrap.dll    
0x0000000075d80000 0x19d000 C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll    
0x0000000076c90000 0x27000 C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll    
0x0000000075990000 0x8f000 C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll    
0x00000000760b0000 0x15c000 C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll    
0x0000000075d60000 0x12000 C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll    
0x00000000739b0000 0x33000 C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrap.dll    
0x0000000074010000 0x16000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPTSP.dll\rsaenh.dll    
0x0000000066480000 0x15000 C:\Python33\DLLs\python3.dll    
0x0000000065990000 0x41000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtSql.pyd    
0x000000006a350000 0x34000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtSql4.dll    
0x000000006a4f0000 0x273000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore4.dll    
0x0000000076b10000 0x35000 C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll    
0x00000000763f0000 0x6000 C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll    
0x000000006f3d0000 0x69000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP100.dll    
0x00000000685c0000 0x80d000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll    
0x0000000076990000 0x7b000 C:\Windows\syswow64\COMDLG32.dll    
0x0000000073270000 0x84000 C:\Windows\WinSxS_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\COMCTL32.dll    
0x00000000718f0000 0x32000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINMM.dll    
0x0000000075610000 0x51000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINSPOOL.DRV    
0x0000000065970000 0x15000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sip.pyd    
0x0000000050d20000 0x19c000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd    
0x0000000050770000 0x5ad000 C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd    
0x0000000073bd0000 0x4c000 C:\Windows\SysWOW64pphelp.dll
```

Comment: @eryksun Hi, thanks for the help! Unfortunately python.exe crashes before I get the chance to import _socket. I noticed though that there are a lot of dll modules missing when i open python.exe in dependency walker. I'll post the dependencies missing and the log output anyways.

Comment: I'm not sure... I'll post the output in another edit

Comment: Also, my system is 64 bits but I'm using python 32 bits

Comment: @eryksun Done, but I get the Windows error message "'listdlls' not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Where is listdlls usually located in Windows? I'm looking for it but can't find it. It doesn't seem to be in System32...

Comment: Ok I downloaded it, posting output

Comment: With ws2_32.dll (Winsock) already loaded, you should be able to load _socket.pyd. Try it manually: `_socket = imp.load_dynamic('_socket', r'C:\Python33\DLLs\_socket.pyd')`.

Comment: That worked! How can I fix this permanently now?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What should I be looking for? It works when i import imp and use that load dinamic function, but not from a fresh terminal window...
EDIT: just saw your new comment, trying it now

Comment: Ok, I got ['C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python33\\DLLs']

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be using Python 2.7...
Output: "C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs"

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot!! If you'd like to post that as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output from listdlls.exe shows that there's no problem loading the dependency ws2_32.dll (Winsock), which would be surprising to say the least. So the problem is that it's trying to load the wrong _socket.pyd.

In the comments it was confirmed that loading _socket.pyd worked when an absolute path was passed to `imp.load_dynamic`. It turns out that the system had the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` set to include `C:\Python27\DLLs`. The solution was to simply unset this environment variable.

I was thrown off by the error message. Normally such a case would raise an error that the shared library is compiled for a different Python version. However, _socket.pyd for Python 2.7 links with msvcr90.dll. This DLL isn't on the DLL search path. It's in a subdirectory of `%windir%\WinSxS`. It's found by consulting the activation context of `C:\Python27\python.exe`, which specifies the C runtime dependency in its embedded manifest:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity 
            type="win32" 
            name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" 
            version="9.0.21022.8" 
            processorArchitecture="x86" 
            publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
        </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

So when running under `C:\Python33\python.exe`, trying to load the 2.7 _socket.pyd raises the following exception:

```
>>> imp.load_dynamic('_socket', r'C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

3.3 and 3.4 are built with Visual Studio 2010 instead of 2008, which switched back to installing msvcr100.dll on the normal search path. So for comparison here's the error I get when I try to import the 3.3 version of `_socket.pyd` within 3.4:

```
>>> imp.load_dynamic('_socket', r'C:\Python33\DLLs\_socket.pyd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Module use of python33.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Comment: +1. To summarize: the issue is that a directory with Python 2.7 modules is earlier in `sys.path` (`PYTHONPATH` envvar is set) when running Python 3. And the non-explicit error message is because `msvcr90.dll` (necessary for Python 2.7 C extension modules) is unavailable in Python 3 environment.  Unrelated: `msvcr90.dll` corresponds to "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008" and `msvcr80.dll` -- "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005".