# File can be found in console but can't be found using run tool window

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm on OS X.

The structure is:

```
/Project
 /src
  codeA.py
  codeB.py
 /Data
  data.txt
```

`src` is marked as Sources Root and `Data` is marked as Resource root.

The problem is if I write in codeA.py

```
import codeB
with open("./Data/data.txt",'r'):
    pass
```

If I

1. Execute code line by line in console, the file can be found.
2. Execute by clicking "Run code.py" I'll get No Such File error.
3. Execute codeA.py in terminal, I can not even import codeB.

If I write `../Data/data.txt` instead, then method 2 can run but method 1 will get No Such File Error.

I've checked project interpreter path and console path. They are the same.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use raw relative path, you can get current file path with `__file__` and work out your path to `data.txt` from it. That will allow you to run your project from anywhere without having to worries about paths.

Comment: @Cyrbil Nice suggestion! Many thanks for that. But I still want to know why I run into that problem :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pycharm's console will include project root to `PYTHONPATH`. You can see and set this in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console`.

Your run config is probably wrong, ensure the working directory is correct, and that `Add content/source roots to PYTHONPATH` checkboxes are checked.

[image]

To avoid any path problem, it is advised to work with absolute path:

```
# get project path from main entry file
file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
project_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_path, os.path.pardir))

data_path = os.path.join(project_path, 'Data/data.txt')
```

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly. But since `__file__` can only be used when the whole file is executed. What should I use when I'm developing the code in Ipython Console?

Comment: You can run `iPython` in the correct path, or [change current path programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8248430/956660).