# Choose file from python file directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have had an issue for a while where I can't seem to open a file that is starting at the directory of the py file that't running it *for example:*`file = open("commands/command.py")` would look for a file at the root of my drive, but I have that "commands" folder in a directory my python file is in.  I am not sure if there is some way to tell it in the path to look for a directory in the directory of the py file, but any suggestions are great!

*-Max*

edit: i'm on windows by the way

Comment: `print(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir))`

Comment: @Stephen Raunch Thanks!  How would you change the current directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248397/how-to-know-change-current-directory-in-python-shell/