# Create Shell script that runs python script in current directory

Tags: bash, shell, centos

I am a complete noob.
I would like to create a shell script in centOS7 that does these 3 steps and I don't even know where to begin :

1. Run somepythonscript.py in currently opened directory (folder) in terminal. *(The python script will create `.dat` file called `NCS.dat` inside this directory)*
2. rename the file `NCS.dat` with name of the folder that is 2 levels above
   *(so if the path to the file is `FolderName1/FolderName2/NCS.dat` I want the `NCS.dat` be renamed to `FolderName1.dat`)*
3. move the renamed `.dat` file to some other random folder X.

Hope I made it clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
python somescript.py 
var=$(cd .. && cd .. &&  basename "${PWD}")
mv NCS.dat $var.dat
mv $var.dat /someotherpath/$var.dat
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really useful!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the python file using the python run command. For example,

```
>> python runsomepyfile.py <ARGS>
```

To get python to read from a specific directory you can use os module to set your path and run operations from there.

See: [How to know/change current directory in Python shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248397/how-to-know-change-current-directory-in-python-shell)